# Backbone Marionette - appRouter not firing url associated method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, backbone.js, marionette, router

I am testing my router by logging to console. It seems that my router recognizes the proper function i.e. If I use any other name my console complains: "Error: Method 'list' was not found on the controller"

However, when I navigate to my rootURL/#wall nothing is written to console.

```
@TMH.module "WallModule", (WallModule, App, Backbone, Marionette, $, _) ->

  class WallModule.Router extends Marionette.AppRouter
    appRoutes:
        "wall" : "listSections"

  API =
    listSections: ->
        console.log "inside API.listSections"

  App.addInitializer ->
    new WallModule.Router
        controller: API
```

---

```
@TMH = do (Backbone, Marionette) ->

App = new Marionette.Application


App.addRegions

    headerRegion:           "header"
    navigationRegion:       "#navigation"
    mainRegion:             "#main"
    socialBar:          "#social"
    interactionsRegion:     "#interactions"

App.addInitializer ->
    App.module("HeaderApp").start()
    App.module("NavigationApp").start()
    App.module("InteractionsApp").start()

App.on "initialize:after", ->
   if Backbone.history
    Backbone.history.start()
    Backbone.history.navigate("wall", trigger: true) if Backbone.history.fragment is ""

App
```

Notes:

- If I navigate without using a # I get a Ruby on Rails routing error.
- If I use API.listSections() instead of just API, it calls the function, but it seems to be incorrect due to the fact it gives me another method not found error.

Sorry I am new to this. I'm following the tutorials from BackboneRails.com and I may have missed something

Thanks!